# Mean reversion and ergodic processes.

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $\vartheta(t)$ be a real ergodic continuous Markov chain solution to the stochastic differential equation
$$
\mathrm{d}\vartheta(t)=A_1(\vartheta(t),t)\mathrm{d}t+A_2(\vartheta(t),t)\mathrm{d}W(t)
$$
for $A_1,A_2$ unknown $\sigma$-finite functions and $W(t)$ the standard Brownian motion satisfying the usual conditions. Define the transition operator $H$ as
$$
(H_tg)(a)=\mathbb{E}(g(\vartheta(t))\mid \vartheta_0=a)
$$
where $g$ is an arbitrary Borel-measurable function in $\mathbb{R}$. Assume that $H_t$ satisfies
$$
|H_s|_{2}=\sup_{g,\mathbb{E}g(X)=0}\frac{\mathbb{E}^{1/2}(H_sg)^2(X)}{\mathbb{E}^{1/2}g^2(X)}<1
$$
for some $s>0$. At last, assume that the conditional density $p_{\ell}(x\mid y)$ of $\vartheta_{t+\ell}$ given $\vartheta_t$ is continuous in the arguments $(x,y)$ and bounded and that the density $p(x)$ is bounded and time-invariant.

Then is the process $\vartheta(t)$ necessary mean-reverting, or a similar type of characteristic that pulls the process to its unconditional mean? And if not, does there exists conditions on the operators $A_1$ and $A_2$ that achieve this?

For some additional information, the operator $|\cdot|_2$ is called the Rosenblatt condition in the book [nonparametric techniques in statistical inference](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/AD0720284). The condition is used in the paper by Fan, Fan and Lv [Aggregation of Nonparametric Estimators for Volatility Matrix](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701107.pdf) for their aggregated estimator for the diffusion operator using a kernel estimator, which requires the above conditions, among others, to be satisfied.